# Odd Behavior in Struct Char Array

Tags: c++, struct, cout

I'm storing a c++ `const char*` into a struct that is defined in a header like this:

```
struct Info {
  const char* data;
};
```

I then have an instance of the struct in the class header:

```
class System {
  Info info; 
}
```

I set it like this:

```
info.data = myStr.c_str();
```

I then print it a few times like this:

```
std::cout << info.data;
```

However the weird thing is, the first two times I print it out it works fine, displaying the correct string. However the third time I do it I get this:

```
Output: ���
```

With the three random binary byte characters (question marks).

I don't touch the variable at all between each print. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: What happens between the various prints of `info.data`?  Almost assuredly, something illegal or "undefined" is done which causes an inadvertent change to either the pointer or the string.

Comment: @wallyk Nothing happens to it, but what do you think of J Trana's answer? I think the c_str() gets deleted. Do I need to make a copy of the c_str buffer?

Comment: Yes, but what else happens?  Almost assuredly there is a wild pointer being written through, or an out-of-bounds array element written to.

Comment: @wallyk It's a bit difficult to say exactly what happens in the memory stack between when I allocate it and when I print it. I load some files, copy some data, that kind of thing. Are you saying this because I'm getting some odd data that is oddly null terminated at the old memory address c_str() pointed to? Couldn't that just be anything using that area of the heap?

Comment: Let's see the code that "copies some data".  Something like that is writing outside the area it is supposed to.

Comment: @wallyk It... seriously is way too long to post here. Thank you for your concern but after I cleaned up every single usage of c_str() to actually copy to a proper buffer and freed all the memory at the correct time, it's all working fine. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you've already ruled this out, but almost every time this happens to me it's because I didn't watch the scope of the string I was calling .c_str() on. The const char* doesn't live after the string dies and you get this behavior.

Comment: This makes total sense. How do I prevent the const char* from being freed?

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know you can't - you have to make a copy yourself.

Comment: Okay, and you can do it like this: `char * cstr = new char[str.length()+1]; std::strcpy (cstr, str.c_str());` Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianStewart: even better, you could store the result of `new` in a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

what **c_str()** returns is a pointer to a buffer that's managed by the myStr's data type object. It will be deallocated when the string is destroyed, after which the pointer will no longer be valid. The pointer will also be invalidated if you modify the string.
Though you did mentioned that you do nothing between each output, but who knows what happened actually in the memory, so I would suggest instead of assigning a pointer to info.data, copy the value of myStr to info.data.